# InfoPath form web part breaks SharePoint branding

Tags: infopath

I found that adding an InfoPath form web part to a page broke a lot of the custom branding we have added to our site. Inspecting the html, I noticed that a second reference to core.css had been added at the very end of the  element, and after references to our custom CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the copy of the core.css that I wanted to keep actually included a querystring (core.css?somerandomlookinglettersandnumbers) so I simply disabled the offending core.css stylesheet as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var currSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        var compString = "/_layouts/1033/styles/core.css";
        var longCompString = "http://" + window.location.host + compString;
        if (currSheet.href == compString || currSheet.href == longCompString)
        {
            currSheet.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I created a new page layout for InfoPath forms and added this script at the very end of the  tag (i.e. just before the  closing tag for this section)